# Laravel page is blank in the app running on production environment

Tags: php, linux, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

When I access the URL `alertweb.com.br/login` I can see a blank page on production but in the developer env. is working fine... I have no idea... Any suggestions?

My routes

```
Route::get('/', 'WebSite\IndexController@index');

Route::get('/home', 'WebSite\IndexController@index');

Route::get('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
```

Controller

```
 public function showLoginForm()
{   
    if(!\Auth::check()){
        return view('login.index');
    }else{
        return view('manager.index');
    }

}
```

The initial page is working and database connection is established.

Comment: Please add more details, especially the relevant code from `Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm`. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I think you must configure your production server (apache or nginx) to define correct Rewrite conditions.

Comment: try this line by SSH into your server     sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/your-project/storage

Comment: @Jomoos update the question with controller

Comment: @DhavalChheda not working

Comment: @TaronSaribekyan how configure this? principal page is working, but others routes not working.

Comment: @DéboraGonçalves I see you already fixed the problem. FYI your server is apache and `mod_rewrite` is enabled (as you can configure rewrite conditions using .htacess). :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change my .htaccess, and this working.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /public
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
</IfModule>

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php71 .php
RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Clear your configurations and run these commands one by one.

```
        php artisan clear-compiled
        php artisan cache:clear
        php artisan route:clear
        php artisan view:clear
        php artisan config:clear
```

Hope this helps